# First Computer in TOOLS option in CV is confusing

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

While updating my CV, I found TOOLS option with two fields : **First Computer** & **Favourite Editor**.

What should I write in **First Computer** - OS or processor details or something else. The name First Computer sounds inappropriate to me after seeing hint which says:

> Which computer was most influential to you as a budding programmer

[image]

Comment: This makes even less sense for the younger generation who most likely had PCs with _at least_ Pentium 4 as their first serious computer, and it'll continue to make less sense as custom built PCs slowly take over pre-built models.

Comment: Seems a little ageist actually. By putting in my *first* computer I would be aging myself quite significantly.

Comment: First: [Olivetti Programma 101](http://royal.pingdom.com/2012/08/28/the-first-pc-from-1965/). Most influential: DEC VAX 11/780 running VAX/VMS. More useful might be the age at which you caught the programming bug. (In my case, paleolithic.) Or just ignore it.

Comment: TBH I don't see any reasons why should someone whose first computer was Commodore 64 to be treated differently than someone whose first computer was Mac Book Gold? I know programmers who got their first computer being sophomores and they program just fine.

Comment: At the age of nine I constructed a self-learning computer from matchboxes, Smarties, and indelible marker for the game Hex-a-Pawn as described here.: http://johncooksmathblog.blogspot.ca/2014/07/crafts-time.html (At that time, featured in the Reader's Digest Treasury for Young Readers, courtesy of Martin Gardner. I'm not quite sure how to meaningfully describe that in the form provided.

Comment: The obvious second challenge was then to maximize the number of losing games for the Hex-A-Pawn Educational Robot (and thus the number of Smarties consumed by its teacher) in the minimum time (ie number of games).

Comment: I am surprised to see 5 downvotes on my question. How can people get offended by such question....:D  Downvoters atleast share the reason of feeling offfended.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I would also find the question confusing and also irrelevant. For many people their first, and even the most influential computer are old history, the sort of thing that should have fallen off of the out-of-date end of the CV. (Who remembers the Arcturus 18C? Outside of a museum, who cares?)

There is a big difference between "first computer" and "Which computer was most influential to you as a budding programmer". Does anyone remember the Arcturus 18C and what potential employer would want to know that it was my first computer?

What sort of values make sense for the CVS of younger people. Does it matter which company made their first computer? The only significant differences seem to be the form factor (laptop, tablet, desk, mobile phone, etc) and the operating system (MacOs, Linux, Windows, Android, etc). These two characteristics are so broad as to be of little use. Many people will have experience of many of them.

I would leave the question blank.

Comment: An absolutely pointless item, it seems.

Comment: I wouldn't just leave the question blank, I'd stop asking the question all together.  When I first saw it I wondered to myself why in the heck is this even being asked on a cv?

Comment: Seeing a computer doesn't have to be that thing with a mouse and a keyboard, I believe the _Nintendo Entertainment System_ (NES) is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I agree that the NES would be a valid answer on the CV. My point is that the question is irrelevant. Would you employ someone who first worked on programming the NES over someone who first worked on programming a PET or over someone who first worked on a programming a PC, etc?

Comment: Well it certainly won't add any value. But when I look over an applicant's CV I do like a touch of personality. The standard "I did this and I did that" is all good for a senior position, but a trainee or junior position I/we value personality and the ability to learn (much) more than experience.

Answer (score 12):

I thought it was a fun question, but then again, my first computer was the Commodore64 (which was more of a game console, really).

There's no right or wrong answer here, but you may want to consider filling in something that would help you stand out as an applicant.  I don't think *what* it was is nearly as valuable as *why* it was influential.  While listing old or rare architecture is cool in its own way, I would think computer that has an interesting story behind it would be entirely appropriate here (eg. my dad brought home an old i386 and putting it together with him sparked my interest in computing).

Of course, if you can't think of anything useful to put here, it can be left blank.