# "What was your first love personal computer?" Really?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

> ### Moderator note
>
> Please refrain from answering or commenting about your first computer/love/both. This is not the place for that. Please keep the discussion on topic.

---

I was trying out a developer story when I noticed the placeholder text for one of the questions is indeed:

> What was your first love personal computer?

Evidence:

[image]

Comment: I don't even know what that question means, because it's not really grammatically well-formed English. My first computer? My first love? My first computer that I loved? Because I did not love my first computer, and my first love was not a computer.

Comment: I understood it as a My first computer that I loved  @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: @stuartd, sorry, I don't follow, did you really interpret that as *intercourse with a machine?*

Comment: @stuartd, ah, that's what I thought. And that's legal, by the way ;)

Comment: The placeholder text should be an example answer or explain what an answer should look like, like the placeholders in the fields above it do.

Comment: It is just a simple trick to get you to disclose something that they cannot legally ask you.  Pretty effective, if you don't answer it then it looks like you don't like computers.  If you do answer it then they can tell you how old you are.  You'd be wise to pick, say, an iPhone unless you want to aim high.

Comment: @HansPassant I think they already collected our age in the developer survey ;)

Comment: Come on! It's only missing a comma: "What was your first love, personal computer?" *\*beep boop\**

Comment: @T3H40 Maybe it's only missing a d: "What was your first loved personal computer?" Admit it, you've loved more than one! :)

Comment: @PetahChristian true, but there were always the other ones as well... :)

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315715/first-computer-in-tools-option-in-cv-is-confusing

Comment: Suggesting to migrate to [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: My first love’s personal computer? How should I know?

Comment: This post did not deliver the OT goodness I was expecting. :/

Comment: Maybe just me: but does really someone want to know that?

Comment: I was looking at this earlier today remembering how awkward I felt filling that box in

Comment: *It is just a simple trick to get you to disclose something that they cannot legally ask you.* @HansPassant - In the United States it's completely legal to ask, they just can't make a hiring decision based on age. They ought not to ask if they don't want the appearance of making hiring decisions based on age, but asking the question by itself is not a violation of the law.

Comment: "Let's eat Grandpa" no I mean "Let's eat, Grandpa". Correct punctuation can save a person's life :D

Comment: There's the grammar problem but I'm more concerned about the relevance of the question. Am I supposed to boast about how soon I used computers? Is it in case some hiring agency is looking for somebody able to write an ENIAC program ? And it's full of ambiguity as the visible title is "First Computer" but I seem to be asked the most influential one.

Comment: SO, get a life.  Hire a copywriter or a marketing professional. Illiterates trying to be "funny!" is embarrassing.

Comment: I just assumed the question was not addressed to me, and left it for my personal computer to answer. Not sure how he responded.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is (in this meta question). "really?" doesn't actually communicate what the problem is. Are we complaining about grammar, or appropriateness of a "first computer" question?

Comment: Better to just hyphenate "first-love". It's simple, correct and more readable; some dictionaries list it that way anyway. Like this: "What was your first-love personal computer?"

Comment: I notice a distinct lack of emacs in that favorite editor field. (Full disclosure, I'm a "Vim all the IDEs" kind of guy)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for pointing it out! You're right - that doesn't make a lot of sense :)

We're replacing it with examples of computers that may have been your first:

> Dell OptiPlex 486SX/25, Amiga 500, Sinclair ZX Spectrum...

It should get deployed at some point today.

Answer (score 93):

I don't like the placeholder wording either. From a grammatical standpoint it irks me, and also from the standpoint of reading it as if English were not my first language it has a strong chance at being misunderstood.

It doesn't need much change though

> **First computer**
> Which personal computer was your "first love"?

Comment: Improvement: _Which personal computer was your "first love or hate"?_ I hate all of them, and beating them hard and extensively every day.

Comment: I think if your answer to that question is what you beat hard and extensively every day then that is a personal choice.

Comment: _"then that is a personal choice"_ Not completely unfortunately, sometimes hardware staff makes some preconditions, also customers may have some weird requirements.

Comment: I'd rather see the word *personal* struck from the text, for the sake of old-timers who loved big iron (mainframes) :p

Comment: Would a native English speaker ever say the original sentence, even if informally?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 Not without air quotes or some emphasis on the "first love". One of the problems with most written language is the lack of ability to express nonverbal cues like this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then interpret "love"  as "some I don't hate that much" then :)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - that's sad.

Comment: @BobJarvis Well, I was joking a bit. My 1st computer I fell in love with was a Commodore VC20 :-P ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - that's sad too. :-) But then, my first digital love was an EDP-18, a computer no one has ever heard of - 2048 18-bit words - the main memory was a rotating drum - you had to wait about 30 seconds for the drum to come up to speed when you powered it on - it had great big blinky push-button lights on the front panel - IT HAD A FRONT PANEL!!!!! It was...(sigh)...great. :-)

Comment: @PetahChristian and for the younger people that never call it a personal computer anymore.

Answer (score 16):

***First love*** is being used here as an [adjective phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase). It's perfectly grammatical, but it's easy to misinterpret as ***personal*** is also an adjective, so the boundary between the two isn't immediately obvious.

***What was your first-love personal computer?*** would be clearer, but unless there's some reason the sentence can only have seven words then rewriting it would be better.

Comment: I'm not sure "first love" *is* being used as an adjective phrase. The article you linked to defines the latter as "a phrase whose head word is an adjective," and it's not very plausible that "first" is the head word in "first love" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)). If you mean that "first love" is intended to modify "computer," then I would agree, but that doesn't mean it's done in a perfectly grammatical way.

Comment: Then there's a hyphen missing.

Comment: Would "first beloved" be more correct ?

Comment: Agree with hyphenating first-love. I think it's a compound word, not adjective phrase.

Answer (score 3):

The field is simply called "First computer" so then mentioning love (or any other emotion) in the placeholder answer text seems odd. The first computer you owned - or at least used - is what I'd consider the starting point for your developer story (even if you didn't do any developing with it), but you may not have loved it.

I'd suggest the placeholder text should simply be:

> What was your first personal computer?

or

> What was the first computer you used?

Answer (score 0):

It reads like a typo to me. I wonder whether the author was absent-mindedly typing "What was your first computer" and automatically added the "love" part because the common phrase "first love" popped into his/her head. 
Proofreading FTW...

Answer (score -2):

I vote for auto-complete adding the word love, without anyone to proofread the output. I may be completely mistaken, but that's how it looks like to me. Because otherwise the sentence makes no sense.

Answer (score -8):

first love is a kind of phrase here. This question means which is your first personal computer, as u always remember your first love likewise you remember your first computer.

Comment: This is actually the right answer. The expression 'first love' is being used adjectivally.

Comment: thanx , i don know on what point they are arguing! It is used here as a adjective (your first PC ). Its your first that's y u luv it!

Comment: "first love" doesn't necessarily equal "first". Your first owned computer might have been one you didn't like. And so on.

Comment: Exactly ! but this a phrase it is meant to be like that. You can't argue why a Cup of Tea, why not a Cup of Coffee

Comment: @vivek People do say "a cup of coffee"...

Answer (score -16):

Is the question perhaps missing a slash, as in:

> What was your first love / personal computer?

Maybe there is a filter for non alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Why would the form ask about your first love?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit some people loved cookies before computers :) - such people are immediately excluded from usage of SO/Jobs sites... (Clearly not asking about person - "what" vs. "who")

Comment: As [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yF9NQ.png) shows, there is no slash in the placeholder text.

Comment: @stuartd My point is what if the slash was removed unbeknownst to the author?

Comment: @user1886721 well, that's what source control is for.